# How can average time between an event and the average time to wait for an event be different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This was prompted by a discussion in class. We are told that there is an event that happens a certain k times a day, and the average time between two instances of this occurring is 7.5 minutes. At the same time it can be true that someone who, at some random time everyday, decides to wait for an occurrence of the event will wait an average of 15 minutes.

We also know that the events occur at the same time every day, and the interval time can be zero. Also, everything happens at the start of the minute.

How can this be possible? It seems contradictory?

Comment: There is a particular relationship between the distribution of waiting times $X$ and the length of the interval containing a particular time, $\hat X$, discussed in [this answer by Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/626947/177399). Specifically, $\hat X$ is the size-biased version of $X$, and satisfies $P(\hat X\ge x)=E[X{\bf 1}_{X\ge x}]/E[X]$. The expected wait time for a random person is then $E[\hat X]/2$. You just need to find a discrete distribution $X$ for which $E[X]=7.5$ and $E[\hat X]/2=15$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest The OP's events *"occur at the same time every day"*, so they're not random. The only time said to be random is the starting time for waiting until the next scheduled event. (In this scenario, too, the expected waiting time can well be larger than the average time between the scheduled events.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Huh, I see. That makes the problem much less interesting (it is also misleading to say "the average wait time between two instances ... is $7.5$ minutes" when the wait time is deterministic).

Comment: @MikeEarnest I read it like this: For scheduled event times repeating periodically as a group, there will be some average time between events. The wait time is not deterministic, as a random time to start waiting will produce a random waiting time until the next scheduled event.

Answer (score 0):

The time interval between two instances of the event might be very short sometimes and very long at other times, so that the average time is $7.5$ minutes. A person arriving at a random time is more likely to arrive during a long interval than during a short one. So the person's waiting time be longer than $7.5$ minutes.

Comment: *"A person arriving at a random time is more likely to arrive during a long interval than during a short one."* Not necessarily. For example, in the $1440$ minutes of a day, there could be $1000$ inter-occurrence times equal to $1$ minute, followed by a few inter-occurrence times of $100$ minutes, making it more likely that a random time will fall into one of the shorter intervals.

Answer (score 0):

For example, it may happen that $3k/4$ of the events happen exactly at midnight, and the other $k/4$ events happen exactly evenly spaced throughout the day in 30 minute intervals. Then three quarters of the intervals have length 0, and one quarter of the intervals have length 30, so the average interval length is 7.5 minutes. However, if you arrive, it will always be in a 30 minute interval, and you have to wait on average 15 minutes for the next event.

Comment: The OP says *"everything happens at the start of the minute"* -- the event times, the start time and wait time are all ***discrete***. If every day all events occur among $48$ equally-spaced times (hitting all of them), then the expected discrete wait time is $14.5$ (not $15$); also, *irrespective of the event-times*, the mean time between events is always $1440/k$ (so $k=1440/7.5=192$), hence it isn't possible to schedule $3k/4=144$ simultaneous and $k/4=48$ separate events in the way you describe. (See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4098865/16397).)

Comment: @r.e.s. I think you are reading too much into the question. This waiting time 'paradox' is a standard example in probability theory. The finer details of how this works when dividing the day into discrete minutes is unrelated and uninteresting, and therefore much less likely to be the point of the question. Reading OP's "everything" as pertaining only to the bus schedule makes the whole thing a lot more sensible. (Even if we take your interpretation, the question does not specify what happens if someone arrives at the exact moment that the bus departs.)

Comment: Perhaps you're right that the "standard example" was intended, but the [combinatorics] [discrete-mathematics] tags make the "all-discrete" reading seem appropriate. (I added the [probability] tag.) I do think the all-discrete case is not altogether "uninteresting"; e.g., the unsolved problem of whether $15$ is an attainable expected value. In any case, even if it's only the scheduled event-times that are restricted to $\{0,1,...,1439\}$ (never mind the start time), you still cannot allocate $3k/4=144$ simultaneous and $k/4=48$ separate events to $48$ different times in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
The issue with the given information is not whether the mean time between the events can be so different from the expected wait time (it can); rather, a potential issue is whether the wait time can have an expectation equal to $15.$

> there is an event that happens a certain k times a day [...] the events occur at the same time every day, and the interval time can be zero. Also, everything happens at the start of the minute.

Because the "events occur at the same time every day", we can suppose the events are scheduled at fixed times $t_1\le...\le t_k,$ and because "everything happens at the start of the minute", we can suppose these times are in the set $\{0,1,...,1439\}$ (there being $1440$ minutes in a day). The fixed times between these scheduled events are then $t_1+(1440-t_k),t_2-t_1,t_3-t_2,...,t_k-t_{k-1},$  noting that $t_1+(1440-t_k)$ is the time elapsed between the last event-time on one day and the first event-time on the next day.

**NB**: The mean time between the scheduled events *does not depend on* the event-times:
$$\begin{align}&\text{mean}\{t_1+(1440-t_k),t_2-t_1,t_3-t_2,...,t_k-t_{k-1}\}\\[2ex]
&={\text{sum}\{t_1+(1440-t_k),t_2-t_1,t_3-t_2,...,t_k-t_{k-1}\}\over k}\\[2ex]
&={1440\over k}.
\end{align}$$
(Since it is given that this mean equals $7.5$, we can infer that $k={1440\over 7.5}=192.$)

On the other hand, let $W$ be the wait time between a random starting-time $U\in\{0,1,...,1439\}$ and the least scheduled event time not less than $U.$ Clearly the expected value of $W$ can be much different than the mean time between scheduled events; for example, if all events happen at time $0$, then, no matter the value of $k$,  $$E(W)=(0)p+(1440-1)p+(1440-2)p+...+(1440-1439)p\\ ={1439\cdot 1440\over 2}p={1439\over 2},$$ where $p=1/1440$ is the probability of any one of the $1440$ minutes of the day. As another example, suppose every event time is a multiple of $30$ minutes and that every multiple of $30$ minutes is an event time; then, because of the equal spacing, the expectation can be found from the behavior in one interval: $$E(W)=(0)p+(30-1)p+(30-2)p+...+(30-29)p\\ ={29\cdot 30\over 2}p=29/2=14.5,$$ where $p=1/30$ is the probability of choosing any particular time in $\{0,1,2,...,29\}.$

**NB**: If the starting time had a **continuous** uniform distribution, then the latter expectation would be exactly $15$; but the information as-stated requires a discrete distribution of $U$ on the $1440$ minutes in a day. So the issue with the given information is not whether the mean time ($7.5$) between events can be so different from the expected wait time ($15$); rather, a potential issue is whether the **discrete** wait time can have an expectation equal to $15.$

To explore this, let's express $W$ as a function of $U$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}W(U)
&= (t_1-U)[0\le U\le t_1]\\
&\ +(t_2-U)[t_1<U\le t_2]\\
&...\\
&\ +(t_k-U)[t_{k-1}<U\le t_k]\\
&\ +(1440-U+t_1)[t_k<U\le 1439]\\
\end{align}$$
where [...] are Iverson indicator brackets. By the linearity of expectation we then have the following explicit formula for the expected wait time:

$$\begin{align}&E(W(U))\\[2ex]
&=\sum_u P(U=u)W(u)\\[2ex]
&= {1\over 1440}\left(
\sum_{0\le u\le t_1}(t_1-u)+...
+\sum_{t_{k-1}<u\le t_k}(t_k-u)
+\sum_{t_k<u\le 1439}(1440-u+t_1)\right)\\[2ex]
&= {1\over 1440}\left(\sum_{0\le u\le t_1}t_1
+\sum_{t_1<u\le t_2}t_2+...
+\sum_{t_{k-1}<u\le t_k}t_k
+\sum_{t_k<u\le 1439}(1440+t_1)
\right)-E(U)\\[2ex]
&={(t_1+1)t_1
+(t_2-t_1)t_2+...
+(t_k-t_{k-1})t_k
+(1439-t_k)(1440+t_1)\over 1440}
-{1439\over 2}\\[2ex]
&={\sum_{i=1}^kt_i^2 - \sum_{i=2}^k t_{i-1} t_{i} - t_kt_1 \over 1440} - (t_k-t_1) + {1439\over 2}
\end{align}$$

"Exercise for the reader": For $k=192$, determine whether there exist $t_1,...,t_k\in \{0,1,...,1439\}$ such that $$(t_1+1)t_1
+(t_2-t_1)t_2+...
+(t_k-t_{k-1})t_k
+(1439-t_k)(1440+t_1) = 720\cdot 1469.$$